# SVG viewer for a quick browse through many SVG files

Tags: windows, images, image-viewer, svg

I have folders containing a large amount of SVG images. A quick look up is not an option when using software like Adobe Illustrator. What I am looking for is a tool for simply viewing the files.

Comment: You could use Inkscape's *Open File* dialog, which shows a preview image whenever you select a file in that dialog. This is obviously not the most comfortable option, so I just leave this as a comment.

Comment: Found this question while searching for an SVG viewer in 2022. Looks like it is still unanswered after 6 years since asking this question.

Comment: On Linux with Gnome 3 Graphical desktop  I use the Nautilus standard file manager, which can display previews of all SVGs in a folder, in a grid-view, as large tiles, where I zoom out with `CTRL  - `.  Viewer "Geeqie" also works well. But not for Image-Sprites

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) from the command line to view the images or to  create a contact sheet like preview of the contents of each directory, with captions such as the file names and you can do so in a number of output formats including a clickable html preview file.

Lots of options and control available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#html) using the montage command but one example would be:

```
convert 'vid:../img_photos/*.svg' svg_index.html
```

ImageMagick is a command line image manipulation utility suit that is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform, Windows/OS-X/Linux
- Can read and write images in a variety of formats (over 200) including PNG, JPEG, JPEG-2000, GIF, TIFF, DPX, EXR, WebP, Postscript, PDF, and **SVG**.
- Can resize, flip, mirror, rotate, distort, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves.
- Has bindings for a number of programming and scripting languages.

Comment: ImageMagick is a nice tool, but for this case it is not really handy.

Comment: To make it support transparent images, use ``-background none``